# Why is it required to have jstl.jar in WEB-INF/lib in Maven project?

Tags: jsp, maven, jstl

I've a Maven web project in which I've added **JSTL** dependency in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And in `.jsp` file, I've taglib as follows

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

But, eclipse shows error on that line

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

But when I include `jstl.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib`, eclipse doesn't show such error.

My question is,

**Why do I need to have `jstl.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` folder even though JSTL is included in Maven Dependency?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime due to bad internet connection your dependency jar files are not properly downloaded.
be sure before work on maven project you have good internet connection.

Sol no 1: right click on your project, go to properties -> Java Build Path->check on "Maven Dependencies" you must having red cross sign.
That means your jar are missing on the particular path.So you have to solve by update your project ( or manually download the file and paste into the missing path)
your problem solved.

Sol no 2:Please check your internet connection before work on maven projet.

Answer (score 0):

JSTL is used mainly for tags, which is used only in JSP. While compiling this is not required, javac will not bother about JSP files while compiling.

But, while jsp is executing, the JSP will be converted into Java file and it will be compiled before used by container. While doing this, it requires JSTL.jar for converting the JSP tags into proper java code, that's why JSTL.jar is not required while compiling, but required while running the application. Hope this helps you !!!.

you can make the dependency  scope as runtime. maven will include the jar into lib.

Answer (score 0):

It is not required. Reload your maven project in eclipse.

After packaging this project with 'mvn package` check if jstl.jar is inside WAR.